# Can't run 460800 baude rate on Nexys2

Tags: vhdl, uart, spartan

I have Nexys2 Spartan 3E board and I am running Ken Chapman's UART IP core, I need to transmit data to another device at a baude rate of 460800. I was successful in sending data at 115200 and 9600 using 50MHz clock of my board, but when it comes to 460800 I get garbage values. I even tried with 100MHz clock (using DCM) but it did not really work.

Any ideas why I am having these issues?

Comment: If your UART module requires a 16x clock, that would be 7.3728 MHz. The closest you can get using integer division from a 50 MHz clock is 50/7 = 7.1429 MHz, which is an error of a little over 3%, which really should work, as long as the receiving system has less than 1-2% error. Perhaps your driver isn't up to doing that speed. Are you using TTL or RS-232 levels?

Comment: Can you scope the UART signal?

Comment: @DaveTweed I am interfacing my FPGA board directly to a 3.3V PIC controller, PIC24fJ64Gb004. And yes I can scope the UART signal and still not getting anything to the controller, that is the confusing part.

Comment: bring the internal 16x baud clock out to an FPGA pin so you can scope it. and double-check your toplevel pin assignments. Tx output of fpga should drive Rx input if PIC.

Comment: Is your PIC capable of handling such high baudrates? The UART6 can be used with up to 200 MHz [XAP223 from Ken Chapman [original paper, 2008]](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp223.pdf)

Comment: Yes the controller can handle such high baud rates. This XAP223 is not recommended for new designs!